# what is the difference between playn.io and com.googlecode.playn

Tags: playn

I am trying to get started on playn.io via netbeans.
when trying to import maven archetype, I encounter 2 type of playn.
playn.io and com.googlecode.playn

what is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 1):

com.googlecode.playn is its legacy location.
The project was forked to github and active development continued there. You can find the legacy 1.x code here: https://github.com/threerings/playn

New projects should use the 2.x version the code of which is here: https://github.com/playn/playn
Also, this 2.x version is what http://playn.io/ targets.